# Supabase auth.update() email_refresh_token workflow

Tags: vue-router, supabase, supabase-database

When I want to let an authenticated user change their email address I  use auth.update(), found here https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-update

I'm using just a magic link auth, btw.

Right now my project is set up for only one email confirmation.

Im using vue 3 with vu-router v4

When I run this function

```
 async handleUpdateUser(newEmail: string) {
      try {
        const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.update({
          email: newEmail,
        });

        if (error) throw error;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
```

The onAuthStateChange that I log shows as USER_UPDATED, the users.auth table on the server shows the new stuff, and a new_email prop is seen on the user object in the console

My question is how do I make the new_emial into just email.

the link that is sent to the new email  is as so

https://correct_info_is_here.supabase.co/auth/v1/verify?token=there_is_a_token_here&type=email_change&redirect_to=http://localhost:3000/

When I click the link, it redirects to a new window  just like it does when an initial sign up happens, but other than that nothing changes.

I found this answer,
https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/1763

but I have no idea how to implement that procedure. The only way figured out how to get that token is by an rpc function on the client , but I don't know what to do with that token after I receive it.

Also I might add when I use vue-router, I log the to and from properties of the beforeEach like so

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
  console.log("to", to);
  console.log("from", from);...
```

When I load the confirmation link,  it doesn't show anything useful like it does when its redirected form the original sign up link.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue, and in my case, it came down to the "Double confirm email changes" setting in Supabase Studio.

[image: "Double confirm email changes" setting]

From the Supabase docs for `supabase.auth.update`:

> Email updates will send an email to both the user's current and new email with a confirmation link by default. To toggle this behavior off and only send a single confirmation link to the new email, toggle "Double confirm email changes" under "Authentication" -> "Settings" off.

So what may be happening is that when you request the email change, the user receives two emails: one at the old email address, and one at the new email address. **The user must click both links in order for that user's `email` column to actually be updated.**

At least, this was the issue in my case — I hope it helps!